# Help with First Order Logic

Tags: first-order-logic

I am having a hard time understanding how to represent sentences in first order logic. Here is an example I am trying to understand, but I really can't:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fu5i.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tncHS.png)

There's another slide I cannot upload (don't have enough reputation), which says:

> The *"all its children can fly"* part needs to be read as: "*if it's a
> child of the elephant, then it can fly"*
>
> This will be inside another if-then statement:
> *"if all the children of an elephant can fly, then the elephant is happy"*
>
> Then, we need a third
> implication to say that if something is an elephant, then, if all its
> children can fly, it is happy.

The original sentence seems to implicitly state that children of an elephant could also not fly, while according to the explanation: if one is a child, then it can fly (as if this was a direct implication). This seems wrong to me.

I would have said that the 4) is the right answer. I can't understand why 1) is correct instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the last part of (4):

$$\forall y[(child(y, x)\wedge fly(y))\implies happy(x)].$$ Note that I've changed a pair of *curved* braces to *square* braces for improved readability.

The problem is that "$\forall y$" binds too much: the expression above says

> $(*)\quad$ For all $y$, if $y$ is a child of $x$ that flies then $x$ is happy.

Now let's imagine an $x$ that has two children $a$ and $b$, and $a$ flies and $b$ doesn't. Then:

- Clearly $x$ shouldn't be happy.
- BUT, $a$ is a child of $x$ that flies! And $(*)$ says that for any child of $x$, if that child flies then $x$ is happy. So since $a$ flies, $x$ is happy.

This is an instance of the following derivation:

> "$\forall y(P(y)\implies Q(x))$" and "$P(a)$" together imply "$Q(x)$".

Basically, "$\forall y(P(y)\implies Q(x))$" means that *any* $y$ satisfying $P$ triggers the consequent $Q(x)$.

Comment: Thanks Noah, I got the point. But, what about 1)? Is it correct to say that if *a* is a child of *x*, then *a* can fly? It doesn't seem to me that the original sentence *An elephant is happy if all it's children can fly* is saying that.

Comment: @GianlucaJohnMassimiani (1) is saying: "If x is an elephant, then: if (every child of x can fly), then x is happy." Now, "every child of x can fly" is just another way of saying "for all a, if a is a child of x, then a can fly" (this is actually what (1) says directly - what I wrote above was a clearer English interpretation). So (1) is correct.

Comment: Ok thanks, I think I am getting the grasp